Harmonizing modes other than major and minor
Everywhere I turn for a lesson on music theory I see a way to harmonize the major scale (Ionian) and the minor scale (Aeolian) but they never harmonize the other modes of the major scale. Any help filling in the missing harmonies?

Ionian (I - ii - iii - IV - V - vi - vii°)
Dorian (                                 )
Phrygian(                                )
Lydian (                                 )
Mixolydian (                             )
Aeolian (i - ii° - III - iv - V - VI - VII)
Lydian (                                 )


They're just rotations of each other.
For example ...

Ionian: I ii iii  IV   V  vi viio
Dorian:    i  ii III  IV  v   vio VII
Phrygian:      i  II III  iv   vo  VI vii
Lydian             I  II iii  ivo   V  vi vii
Mixolydian:            I  ii iiio  IV   v  vi VII
Aeolian:                   i  iio III  iv   v  VI  VII
Locrian:                       io  II iii  iv   V   VI vii

Here's another way to look at it based on chord quality and where the "tonic" chord is. Start where the mode is listed, continue down the chord quality list, then loop back to the top if necessary.

Ionian      M
Dorian      m
Phrygian    m
Lydian      M
Mixolydian  M
Aeolian     m
Locrian     d

Thus, Phrygian, for example, will be m M M m d M m.

Can you add the rest please

I can, but it will be a couple of hours. Meanwhile, it would be helpful to know what remains unclear about the pattern. I can address that as well.

Actually, I think I get it. You just take the Ionian and shift the I of the scale over one... then take the major/minor indicator from the above scale. Right?

@selectstart Exactly. All of those different modes are really just the same scale but with different starting notes. See this post for a full description.

If you want harmonization that has a historically modal sound, you can follow the examples in Helmore, A Manual of Plain Song...
A very generalized approach is to...

avoid any diminished chords
frequent use of root movements by step, like I VII VI
use plagal cadences, like IV I or VII I

Give special attention to the phrygian mode. It has a unique sound, and the tonic chord changes from minor to major.
Another approach is to look at the counterpoint harmonizations in Fux's Gradus ad Parnassum. The book guides you through counterpoint (harmonization) exercises. If you just look at the 1:1 note against note examples in two, three, and four parts - all given in whole notes - you get a general idea of how chords are handled in various modes. The general idea from a chord point of view is...

start on the tonic chord,
move through just about any chord but avoiding diminished chords,
then end with a V I or V6/4 I cadence, technically a clausula vera, which may require accidentals to get the V chord to include a proper leading tone

Getting back to Helmore. Below are scale harmonizations by Helmore to get an authentic modal flavor.



Very interesting reference. I'm going to check that out.

I cobbled those two pages together from Helmore's book for a handy two sided, single sheet cheat sheet.

The whole point of modes is that each one contains the same notes as its parent scale. Thus C Ionian (major) has exactly the same notes as D Dorian, E Phrygian, F Lydian, G Mixolydian A Aeolian and B Locrian. There are no changes. The difference being which note is deemed to be the 'tonic' or 'home' for each mode.
Therefore, each will have the same harmonies - how could they differ?
So, say in D Dorian, the triad of C maj. belongs, as does the triad of G major, for example. That's the whole essence of modal playing.

I understood the question to be not so much what notes are in each triad, but what is the functional quality of each triad. E.g. does II - V - I still make sense in the locrian mode? (I suspect not :-))
